# kubernetes issue : runtime network not ready

Tags: kubernetes

I am beginner in kubernetes and I'm trying to set up my first cluster , my worker node has joined to my cluster successfully but when I run kubectl get nodes it is in NotReady status .
and this massesge exists when I run

```
kubectl describe node k8s-node-1
```

runtime network not ready: NetworkReady=false reason:NetworkPluginNotReady message:docker: network plugin is not ready: cni config uninitialized

I have run this command to install a a Pod network add-on:

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.14/manifests/calico.yaml
```

how can I solve this issue?

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `kubectl get pods -n kube-system`. If calico pods are not running then describe the pod using `kubectl describe pod podname -n kube-system` and add that output. Also add output of `kubectl get events` as well

Comment: Hi, for this issue I reboot the worker node and the status changed to "ready" . but now I've got a new problem I've explained here : [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63982293/get-https-10-96-0-1443-apis-crd-projectcalico-org-v1-clusterinformations-de] could you help ?

Answer (score 0):

Adding this answer as community wiki for better visibility. OP already solved the problem with rebooting the machine.

Worth to remember that going thru all the steps with [bootstrapping cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/) and installing all the prerequisites will make your cluster running successfully . If you had any previous installations please remember to perform `kubeadm reset` and remove `.kube` folder from the home or root directory.

I`m also linking this [github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/48798) case with the same issue whereas people provide solution for this problem.